# How to enable .net 6,7,8 in target framework in project properties?

Tags: vb.net

I installed .net 6, 7, 8

Yet I cannot see target framework in visual studio

[image]

Look at the pics there.

Doing some command in command prompt shows that I do have .net 6, and 7

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.201
 Commit:    68f2d7e7a3

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.201\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.3
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       0a2bda10e8

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.309 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.406 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Yet I cannot change the target framework of my project beyond 4.8

Comment: You can't convert a framework to core app. Just too many differences. You'll need to make a new app as net 6 or whatever you're looking for.

Comment: Have a look at the [upgrade assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview) though

Comment: Try using [upgrade assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview). There is WinForms specific section.

Comment: Looking at your editor's tabs, there is no evidence we're talking about C# here, so I'll remove that irrelevant tag. You can add it back if you can provide evidence that it's being used.

Comment: No. I am using vb.net

Comment: Can anyone turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out .net6 and .net7 is a different kind of .net compared to .net framework 4.8

.net framework 4.8 is old technology.

To get into .net7 I need to convert the program to core.

And I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview

It works. Only 1-2 code needed to be changed.

I am very happy.